# Laravel 5.4 : Display mulitple rows randomly after clicking a button

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I have a table questions and a table question_options in my database and I want when the user clicks on the button play he will see a random question from the database to answer it, then press the next button and an another question must appear to him, although each question should appear in a 30 seconds. my tables :

```
Schema::create('questions', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('question_text');
    $table->integer('points');
    $table->integer('temps_reponse');

    $table->integer('categories_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('categories_id')->references('id')->on('categories');

    $table->integer('type_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('type_id')->references('id')->on('types');

    $table->timestamps();

});

Schema::create('question_options', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('option_one');
    $table->string('option_two');
    $table->string('option_three');
    $table->string('correcte');

    $table->integer('question_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
    $table->foreign('question_id')->references('id')->on('questions');

    $table->timestamps();

});
```

Can anyone tell me how to solve this. Any help would be really appreciated, thanks much

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) 
if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and 
provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
Read [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). 
Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: @SloanThrasher Thanks for your answer but I tried to solve this before post my question here and i don't wait the full code i want just indices and some suggestion because i'm new in laravel

Comment: try my answer,it works

Comment: why did you remove this as an answer? @toto01 ? that's very rude

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$randomQuestion = DB::table('questions')
                ->inRandomOrder()
                ->get();
```

See Laravel [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset)